# Указатели и ссылки в GoLang

Tags: golang

Здравствуйте. Уже некоторое время пытаюсь 100%-но разобраться в этой теме. Читал и на русском пояснения, и документацию (прохожу A Tour of Go). Проблема возникла с таким примером (как и с остальными в туре, связанными со ссылками):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}

func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}

func AbsFunc(v *Vertex) float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}

func main() {
    v := Vertex{3, 4}
    fmt.Println(v.Abs())
    fmt.Println(AbsFunc(&v))

    p := &Vertex{4, 3}
    fmt.Println(p.Abs())
    fmt.Println(AbsFunc(p))
}
```

Я понимаю так (переменные ниже взяты из головы и никак не относятся к примеру выше):

- **i := 5**
- a := &i - вывод **&a** отдаст нам **ссылку** на **a**, **a** отдаст нам **ссылку** на **i**, ***a** отдаст нам **значение i**.

Если это так, то (теперь все из примера кода выше)   `fmt.Println(AbsFunc(&v))` - почему здесь значение передается ссылкой, если нам в функцию надо передать v *Vertex, тоесть непосредственно значение? Идентично и тут -

```
fmt.Println(p.Abs())
fmt.Println(AbsFunc(p))
```

Мы почему-то передаем ссылку на `&Vertex{4, 3}`, а не значение...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому, что объявление `v *Vertex` говорит, что `v` - это **указатель** на `Vertex`. Соответственно мы и должны передать указатель. А операция `&` не что иное, как взятие адреса. Т.е. вычисление того самого указателя

Answer (score 2):

В Go *нет ссылок*. Есть только **указатели**.

Ссылка -- ссылается на ячейку памяти. Указатель -- указывает на объект в глобальной таблице объектов (нужна для сборщика мусора). Если объект в памяти перемещается -- изменяется ссылка хранимая в указателе на перемещаемый объект. Само значение указателя в глобальной таблице (сиречь -- номер строки) -- остаётся неизменным.